# Tableau - Calculated field of different columns based on different partition of the same table

Tags: tableau-api

Sorry for the stupid question.

Situation: I have a partitioned table (the partition is the week of the year) with some metrics (e.g. frequency of some keywords); I need to run an analysis of metrics belonging to different partitions (e.g. the trend between the frequency of a keyword in week 32 compared to week 3). The ultimate purpose is to create a dashboard where the user can choose the week of the year and is presented with the calculated analysis on the go.

So far I have used a live query that uses two parameters (week_1 and week_2) that joins data from the same table based on the two different parameters. You can imagine that the dashboard recomputes everything once one of the parameter is changed by the user. To avoid long waiting times, I have set the two parameters to a non-existent default value (0, zero), so that the dashboard can open very quickly. Then I prompt the user to stop the dashboard, insert the new parameters of choice, and then restart the dashboard to load the new computations.

My question is: is it possible to achieve the same by using an extract of the table? The table itself should not be excessively big (it should be 15 million records spanning 3 years) and as far as I know the extracts are performant with those numbers.

I am quite new to Tableau, so I would like to know from more expert people if there is a more optimal way to do such a thing without using live queries.

Please, feel free to ask more information if I was not clear! However, I cannot share my workbook, as it contains sensitive information.

**Edit:**

```
+-----------+ -----------+ ------------+
  partition    keyword      frequency
+-----------+ -----------+ ------------+
   202032        hello        5000
   202032        ciao         567
    ...
   202031        hello        2323
   202031        ciao         34567
    ...  
   20203         hello        2
   20203         ciao         1000
```

With the live query, I can join the table where partition = 202032 with the same table where partition - 20203 and make a new table with a column where I compute e.g. a trend between the two frequencies:

```
+----------+ -----------------------+ ---------------+
  keyword      partitions_compared         trend
+----------+ -----------------------+ ---------------+
    hello       202032 - 20203           +1billion %
    ciao        202032 - 20203           +1K %
```

With the live query I join on the keywords.

Thanks a lot in advance and have a great day!

Cheers

Comment: Though you have elaborated much, I am unable to get you.  Please show some screenshots, both what you have and what is desired, so that your problem is understood.

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, I can't show pictures of my tables, as there is sensitive data. I will try to add a visual explanation in the body of the question.